# How to test website in different countries / languages?

Tags: hreflang, localization, ios

So after much effort and pain (I'm an iOS developer, not a web developer), I have my website (https://359north.com) set up to support 16 different languages/countries (thanks https://ahrefs.com - I get 100% on their site audit).  Set up like https://359north.com/it/ etc. for the various country/language combinations.

I thought I would test in the iOS Simulator by setting the country and language to Italia and Italiano.  When I do that, some sites like google.com and Mozilla.org show up correctly in Italian, while others like ibm.com and Microsoft.com do not.

My own site shows up in English, not Italian, and when I search for it in Google (359north) it comes back with a link to the US English site (the main site).

I thought that when the phone appears Italian, I should get the Italian webpage from the the generic URL.

Am I doing something wrong here?  The website is on Github Pages at https://github.com/359north/359north.github.io